# Perl - How to add rows in a hash inside a loop?

Tags: perl

Iam trying to create a simple array KEY => VALUE from a json response, here's my results when I dump the array  but the keys are not what Im excpecting:

```
$VAR1 = 'expectedvalue1';
$VAR2 = 'expectedvalue2';
$VAR3 = 'expectedvalue3';
```

and here's my code that I found some part of it [here](https://www.caveofprogramming.com/perl-tutorial/perl-hashes-a-guide-to-associative-arrays-in-perl.html#:%7E:text=Perl%20Articles,set%20of%20key%2Dvalue%20pairs.) (some comments says that there's backslash missing)

```
my %result = ();
foreach my $row (@json_response){
  $result{ $row->{"json_key"} } = $row->{"json_value"};
}
print Dumper(%result);
```

While I'm trying to get

```
expectedkey1 = expectedvalue1
expectedkey2 = expectedvalue2
expectedkey3 = expectedvalue3
```

Edit : I made a mistake in the names of keys.

Comment: I didn't read the full article you've linked. What you're seeing as your output is Data::Dumper taking a list of values, and assuming each one is one variable passed in. Because hashes in Perl are essentially lists of key/value pairs, they get turned into an argument list when passed to `Dumper`, so you get this `$VAR1` stuff. Run `print Dumper \%result` to pass a reference to Data::Dumper, and you'll see something like `$VAR1 = { "foo" => "bar", ... }`. But that doesn't explain why your output doesn't have the keys as variables. Please [edit] and include the JSON you are parsing, and how.

Comment: The json is correct, I printed in the loop and show the expected key values, and when I did the ```print Dumper \%result``` it showed the expected result O.o well post your answer I'll accept it.. thank you

Comment: The problem we couldn't help you was a typo in your question. That's why I asked to see the data. Your question is well written, but it was incomplete. In the future please include a [mcve] in your questions. I didn't answer but wrote a guess in a comment because it was just that, a guess.

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to get key => value and key/value have the same values?

If you're looking for that, maybe this can help you

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my @array_items = qw(expectedvalue1 expectedvalue2 expectedvalue3);
my %hash_example;

foreach my $value (@array_items) {
        push(@{$hash_example{$value}}, $value);
}

print Dumper(\%hash_example);
```

OUTPUT:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'expectedvalue2' => [
                                'expectedvalue2'
                              ],
          'expectedvalue1' => [
                                'expectedvalue1'
                              ],
          'expectedvalue3' => [
                                'expectedvalue3'
                              ]
        };
```

Comment: My bad I made a mistake in the name of keys, it's corrected now.
And I'm looking foy key => value not key => array, @simbabque answer did the trick thank you very much